# Cannot resolve private DNS names in private hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I have a VPC in AWS, and I want to create aliases for some of my resources on the network. For example, I want to be able to connect to my RDS database with "databasehost". However, I also still want the amazon-provided private DNS names (e.g. `ip-172-31-a-b-c.eu-west-2.compute.internal`) to work.

My VPC has `dnsResolution` and `dnsHostnames` both enabled, and the DHCP options set has options `domain-name = eu-west-2.compute.internal; domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS;`.

I created a private hosted zone, associated to my VPC, for domain name `eu-west-2.compute.internal`, and added a CNAME record for my database, pointing to the DNS name amazon gave me (ending in `rds.amazonaws.com`). That works fine! However, now I can no longer use the `ip-172-31-a-b-c.eu-west-2.compute.internal` DNS names. I'd like to be able to create a record `myec2instance` pointing to `ip-172-31-a-b-c.eu-west-2.compute.internal`, but obviously that won't work if `ip-172-31-a-b-c.eu-west-2.compute.internal` can't be resolved.

Is there any way to keep the AWS-provided DNS hostnames when I set up a private hosted zone?

Answer (score 0):

use your own domain/sub domain not rds.amazonaws.com
and under A name you can select alias (( I know odd but it works )) and choose the server you want to point to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm afraid I don't understand it though. When I set up my PHZ, `databasehost.eu-west-2.compute.internal` routes correctly to my database. The issue is that I lose the AWS-provided DNS names for my EC2 instances when I do that. Your solution still use a PHZ, so that doesn't address my problem (if I've understood)